# remove highlighted text

Tags: c#, openxml

if the text is "aaaaa [i am highlight] bbbb" the openxml will look like

```
<w:Paragraph>
  <w:Run><w:Text>aaaaa</w:Text></w:Run>
  <w:Run>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:highlight w:val="yellow" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:Text>[i am highlight]</w:Text>
  </w:Run>
  <w:Run><w:Text>bbbb</w:Text></w:Run>  
</w:Paragraph>
```

I want to remove this highlight tags all from the document wherever it is present.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide what you have tried but, you can use [`Highlight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.highlight) as follow:

> Defines the Highlight Class. When the object is serialized out as xml,
> its qualified name is w:highlight.

Example:

```
foreach (var highlightItem in doc.Paragraph.Descendants<Highlight>())
{
    highlightItem.Remove();
}
```